# All activity stack will be empty

Tags: android, android-activity, stack, parent-child

```
Intent intent=new Intent(context,MyClass.class);    
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);                    
startActivity(intent);
finish();
```

Above code will finish all the activities in a stack and start a new activity.
When I insert it in one class it works fine,
but in other class the same line are executed and a new activity is also started
but parent activity not finished, it remains open

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i have noticed, that by **intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);** all activities are finished but not the  parent activity.

so if you want to finish parent activity also then you have to call it with startActivityForResult() method